# Writing and retrieving bytes to/from a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I'm trying to write an encryption program in Python which takes a file containing text, runs its through the encryption scheme, and outputs the encrypted text to a file. I also have to append the IV and salt I used for the files decryption later on.

I have two problems, first: I write the IV to the file, then the salt, then an encrypted key, then the ciphertext. But the file looks like this:

```
b'\xcc\xc0\x0bL\x85\x04\x11:8\xce\xd6H\x1d^\xf5U'b'\xd6!\xe6\xd2Y\x17\x7f;\xc3\xea
\xd2Wj\xc3Q\xed'b'+\x90\x87Z\xde\x87\x1c8\xfdDl_\x8f\x8e\xbc\x97&4\xc6\r\xfa\xe0
\x1b\x98\x949\xd2\x10\x13\xdfb@'b'\xb2\xd4\x96\xb7D^\xf08\xa0\xa3\xba\x95\x89\r\xc3h'
```

Which is not what I want because you can still see the notation of the b'xxx'b'yyy' which isn't good because it give clues to the files structure. How can I get around this, to be able to write a few 16 byte keys the the file and then an arbitrary number of bytes of cipher text.

My second problem. When I try to read in from the encrypted file, its coming it as:

```
b"b'\\xcc\\xc0\\x0bL\\"
```

So its like its reading the b'' notation and wrapping it in yet more b'' notation, which is throwing my reading in of the bytes way off.

To write to the file I'm using print statements like so:

```
with open('file.encr', 'w') as f:
    print(decrypt_iv, file=f, end="")
    print(salt, file=f, end="")
    print(key, file=f, end="")
    print(encrypt_iv, file=f, end="")
    print(ciphertext, file=f, end="")
```

I don't know if that's causing issues and I should use write() ?

Comment: Sorry I'm actually doing this program to learn Python. So in using print, I expected to learn how it works, which you have helped me in, so thank you

Comment: I'm using the write() function and it tells me the arg must me a str, not a byte? Is there a way I can just write bytes to the file? Without the notation splitting the write operations up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused because of my use of the print function for printing bytes to the file.

```
with open('file.enc', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(iv)
    f.write(salt)
    f.write(key)
```

And:

```
with open("file.enc", "rb") as f:
    iv = f.read(16)
    salt = f.read(16)
    key = f.read(32)
```

Succeeded in transferring the data.